# Vanilla Javascript split(regex) to match spaces not preceded by a comma?

Tags: javascript, regex

I know, frustratingly, that javascript doesn't support lookbehinds which would make this task really simple.

I have a string that is user-input, so the syntax must be simple so I have a list of lists, the overall list is delimited by spaces, the sublists are delimited by commas. (This is for a search engine, hence why one input catching so much) So it might be like..

Jon, Joe4, Carrie, Steve17A 14, 13, 12, 37

The first list's elements can never contain spaces (so the commaless space is a reliable point) `Jon, Joe4, Carrie, Steve17A` is separated from the second list `14, 13, 12, 7` by a space not preceded by a comma. I can also always count on the first list always be

I've tried a few regexes

- `([^,])(?!,)\s` - doesn't work in a split scenario. In a replace scenario, I could use $1.
- `(?!,\s)` - won't work, for reasons I'm not entirely certain of. It matches spaces that follow a comma.

My intent is to say `List1 = Lists.split(regex)`.

I can concoct something with `replace()`.. Something like

```
List1 = Lists.replace(/([^,])\s+.*/,"$1");
```

which will work in this scenario but it is probably more than needs to be done. Is there a better way, besides invoking XRegExp (if even doable)? I've done quite well to write everything without involving the library that I don't want to bring it in for one use.

Comment: Not sure I get it at all, but why not just `lists.replace(/,\s+/g,',').split(' ');`

Comment: @adeneo Haha, that didn't even occur to me for some absurd reason. I was way overthinking it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1888o6kt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace comma and space with just a comma, and then split on space to get the two groups, then on comma to get the parts

```
var lists  = 'Jon, Joe4, Carrie, Steve17A 14, 13, 12, 37';
var groups = lists.replace(/,\s+/g,',').split(' ');

var parts1 = groups[0].split(',');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/1888o6kt/1/)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, [@adeneo's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28573116/1529630) is simpler.

However, an alternative solution which allows you to emulate lookbehinds is reversing the string and using a lookahead:

```
'Jon, Joe4, Carrie, Steve17A 14, 13, 12, 37'
.split('').reverse().join('')     // Reverse the string
.split(/\s+(?!,)\b/)              // Use lookahead
.reverse()                        // Undo reversion (1)
.map(function(item) {
  return item
    .split('').reverse().join('') // Undo reversion (2)
    .split(/,\s+/);
});
```

Comment: I had considered this briefly but had hoped there would be an easier way. Thanks for putting it together and demonstrating.